# Not display ::ms-clear pseudo element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pseudo-element

I want to disable/remove/not display the [::ms-clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465740.aspx) button that is appearing in input fields in IE. How can I do the following

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear { display: none; }
```

using JavaScript? It is sufficient for me to do this on each HTMLInputElement if that is easier.

(I wish not to use any external libraries such as jQuery)

Comment: Why not just do that in your CSS?

Comment: @Pointy I want to be able to set this dynamically using JavaScript and not rely on a CSS file.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847313/dynamically-add-css-to-page-via-javascript

Comment: The best way I've seen to work with pseudo-elements is to set it using a class in your CSS (e.g. `input.foobar::-ms-clear { display: none; }`), and then setting the class using script (e.g. using `document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")` and then looping through the result). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882325/modify-css-style-for-pseudo-element-after-content-with-jquery

Comment: Thank you for your answers. There is really no way to modify a pseudo element dynamically in JavaScript then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that pseudo-elements are readonly? I am trying to do

```
window.getComputedStyle(this.inputTextElement, "::ms-clear").setProperty("display", "none");
```

but I get exception `NoModificationAllowedError`.

The closest working thing to set this in JavaScript seems to be doing

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '::-ms-clear{display:none};';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```