# Get CSS generated text inside a <td> with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table like this:

```
<table id="orders">
  <tr>
    <td>05/06/2005</td>
    <td>3216549</td>
    <td>description</td>
    <td>2.000,00</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>20,00</td>
    <td><div id="state" class="state-c"> </div></td>
    <td><a href="modify.php?id=222"><span class="bt-edit">EDIT</span></a></td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

the part `<div id="state" class="state-c"> </div>` tells "Approved", "Rejected", etc, and is generated by CSS:

```
.state-c:before {
  content: "Confirmed";
}
```

now I need to get the text value of these table cells, while for all the cells I successfully use `.text()` method, it doesen't get the CSS generated text "Confirmed". I tried to use `getGeneratedStyle`, `.value`, and have been searching for hours for information, but no luck.

My question is: how can I get the generated text inside the `<div id="state" class="state-c"> </div>` which actually is empty if you look at the code?

Comment: What's `getGeneratedStyle`? Did you mean `getComputedStyle`?

Comment: you change the class for change the text ? state-c, state-a, state-r... ?

Comment: Do you mandatorily need with jQuery? Is vanilla JS unacceptable?

Comment: take a look at this, i suggest you should do it this way  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882325/modify-css-style-for-pseudo-element-after-content-with-jquery#11891017

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin (the answer by Blazemonger to be precise)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get it like following using `window.getComputedStyle`.

```js
var text = window.getComputedStyle($('#state')[0], ':before').content
alert(text)
```

```css
.state-c:before {
  content: "Confirmed";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="orders">
  <tr>
    <td>05/06/2005</td>
    <td>3216549</td>
    <td>description</td>
    <td>2.000,00</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>20,00</td>
    <td><div id="state" class="state-c"> </div></td>
    <td><a href="modify.php?id=222"><span class="bt-edit">EDIT</span></a></td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/1n5pw8vk/ Note that the selector should be `.state-c`, not `#state`

Comment: Thanks. But `#state` is working. @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score -2):

```
var s = '.state-c:before { content: "Confirmed";}';
var m = s.match(/"(.*?)"/);
alert(m[1]); // m[1] = quoted
```

just pass the css as a string and get the text inside double quotes. hope this will help you

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you can try .find("#state").text("my text")